# How to control elements using Vue Slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider, vuejs2

I have a bunch of data in the `requests` json object. By default all the data is displayed to the user. Additionally, I have a slider component. I am trying to make functionality such that when the user moves the slider, the elements of the json appear/disappear based on the value of the slider.

For example:

Data:

```
 requests:  [
              {value: 10, name: "foo"},
              {value: 12, name: "bar"},
              {value: 14, name: "foobar"},
              {value: 22, name: "test"},
              {value: 1, name: "testtooo"},
              {value: 8, name: "something"}
            ]
```

By default I want all data to be displayed but when the user moves the slider, I only want data displayed that has `value` greater than current value of the slider.

I've made a JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hvb9hvog/9/

**Question**

How can I modify the `requests` json based on the value of the slider?

Answer (score 6):

Create another computed property for the filteredRequests.

```
 filteredRequests(){
    return this.requests.filter(r => r.value > this.num)
 }
```

And use it to list the requests.

```
<li v-for="request in filteredRequests">
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvb9hvog/12/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed property where you map a threshold into the object data:

```
 computed: {
      myList: function()  {
       return this.requests.map(r=> {
        r.threshold = this.num >= r.value
        return r
    })
```

Use the threshold as v-if condition:

```
 <li v-if="request.threshold" v-for="request in myList">
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLpuf93a/)